# Easy way to resolve JSON schema conditions in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Say I have the following JSON schema:

```
const oneOfConditional = [
      {
        if: {
          properties: {
            type: {
              enum: ["numerical"],
            },
          },
        },
        then: {
          properties: {
            op: {
              default: "=",
              enum: ["=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="],
              metadata: {
                labels: [
                  "is equal to",
                  "is less than",
                  "is greater than",
                  "is less than or equal to",
                  "is greater than or equal to",
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]

const allOfConditional: [
      {
        if: {
          properties: {
            op: {
              enum: ["=", "!="],
            },
            type: {
              enum: ["categorical"],
            },
          },
        },
        then: {
          properties: {
            value: {
              type: "array",
              items: {
                type: "string",
              },
            },
          },
        },
        else: {
          properties: {
            value: {
              type: ["number", "string"],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        if: {
          properties: {
            type: {
              enum: ["datetime"],
            },
          },
        },
        then: {
          properties: {
            format: {
              type: "string",
              default: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]

const complexSchema = {
  title: "Filters",
  type: "array",
  minItems: 0,
  maxItems: 100,
  items: {
    type: "object",
    required: ["column", "type"],
    oneOf: oneOfConditional,
    allOf: allOfConditional,
    properties: {
      type: {
        title: "Type",
        type: "string",
        enum: ["categorical", "datetime", "string", "numerical"],
      },
      op: {
        title: "Operator",
        type: "string",
      },
      conj: {
        title: "Conjunction",
        type: "string",
        default: "AND",
        enum: ["OR", "AND"],
        
      },
      value: {
        title: "value",
     
      },
    },
  },
}
```

For the schema above, I have the following data to be validated on it:

```
[{type:"numerical", op:"", conj:"AND",value:null}]
```

I'm using AJV for validation. I don't just want the resulting errors from the validation though. I also want the same schema, but with the conditionals resolved within the schema. So, I would expect the data above to *resolve* the schema to the following:

```
{
  title: "Filters",
  type: "array",
  minItems: 0,
  maxItems: 100,
  items: {
    items: {
      type: "object",
      required: ["column", "type"],
      properties: {
        type: {
          title: "Type",
          type: "string",
          enum: ["categorical", "datetime", "string", "numerical"],
        },
        op: {
          default: "=",
          enum: ["=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="],
          metadata: {
            labels: [
              "is equal to",
              "is less than",
              "is greater than",
              "is less than or equal to",
              "is greater than or equal to",
            ],
          },
        },
        conj: {
          title: "Conjunction",
          type: "string",
          default: "AND",
          enum: ["OR", "AND"],
        },
        value: {
          title: "value",
          type: ["number", "string"],
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: That's not what JSON Schema does. The `if/then/else` keywords are part of JSON Schema, and so implementations of JSON Schema will know about them and use them accordingly, at run time. It sounds like you want to dynamically construct a schema during run time. JSON Schema will validate JSON data. Why would you expect a schema to be modified based on data? If you really are sure you want to generate a schema at runtime (maybe to output somewhere else), then you'll have to break things up further and roll your own solution. Only do this if you're confident you understand the implications.

Comment: Thank you for your input. My use case is to not just use JSON schema for validation, but also to drive how form fields are displayed based on the data it represents. I found an almost complete solution to this for JS - https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/tree/main/packages/utils . The utils library can be imported into your project and the ‘retrieveSchema’ function can be used to get the conditions-resolved version of your schema.